# synchronous file api for workers, example/tutorials?

Tags: javascript, html5-filesystem

Can any one link me up to a synchronous file api for web workers tutorial/example? i tried but couldn't find any. html5rocks does not seem to have covered it.

http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/file-dir-sys.html#the-synchronous-filesystem-interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Chrome [does not support it yet](https://groups.google.com/group/native-client-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1b2c08c2d7d485e5?pli=1). There is [O'Reilly's book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021360.do) on HTML5 Filesystem API that also covers some basic synchronous API and [here](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781449311384/the-synchronous-api/i_chapter8_d1e2918?reader=#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTk3ODE0NDkzMTEzODQvNTg=) is an online preview of the chapter dedicated to synchronous API. From the preview, it seems like synchronous API is the same as asynchronous.

Comment: hay, thanks @usoban! no one seemed to have a look at this question and i really need this. And the groups thread is kind of old. Chrome has a fast iteration model and it looks like it works now. I tried to reverse engineer the code by looking at the specification and it created the file as far as i can tell. It doesn't give any errors either. And as for the links i will have a look and write back. thanks a ton!

Comment: also on a second (deep) look at the groups thread, it looks like they are talking about pepper API and not html5 sync api. Also if it were the case, it would have been mentioned [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) since the author of the html5rocks tutorial and the  O'Reilly's book is the same guy. He did mention that there is a sync api but he wont be covering it in the tutorial. (probably because workers were not very popular back then).

Comment: True, it's about ppapi, had to read it twice ^^

Found something else, here is Chromium platform status: http://www.chromium.org/developers/web-platform-status#TOC-File-APIs
"Synchronous APIs are in m9 for web workers." Not sure what m9 means exactly :D

Comment: well i know about that.. m9 is milestone (version) 9 and its currently on milestone 16 so.. yea it works :P damn i have known about that page for a long time, just couldn't recall it :P thanks for it.. :D and i could find some stuff from the preview of the book and i guess that is what i needed. thanks a ton :')

Comment: i cant award bounty till 14 hours.. will give it to you when i wake up.. thanks again :)

Comment: chromestatus.com also points to that page. Never forget it! :)